# How can I configure IBM Cloud App ID as part of an open toolchain?

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery, ibm-appid

I am using [IBM Cloud App ID](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/about.html#about) for user management / authentication and [Continuous Delivery](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/index.html#cd_getting_started) with a toolchain to deploy the app to IBM Cloud. There is an API to configure App ID, e.g., to set the password strength or to disable email verification for signup.

How can I use that API within the deploy script of the toolchain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using an IAM (Identity and Access Management) token for the IBM Cloud platform to login, then obtain the App ID credentials to make the API call for the configuration itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Login IBM Cloud api=$CF_TARGET_URL org=$CF_ORG space=$CF_SPACE
bx login -a "$CF_TARGET_URL" --apikey "$IAM_API_KEY" -o "$CF_ORG" -s "$CF_SPACE"


# Set up App ID service
#
# Create service key from which to obtain managementUrl
bx service key-create ${PREFIX}insurance-bot-appid for-pipeline
# managementUrl includes tenantId
APPID_MGMT_URL=`bx service key-show ${PREFIX}insurance-bot-appid for-pipeline | grep "\"managementUrl\"" | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '","'`
# We need the IAM token
IAM_OAUTH_TOKEN=`bx iam oauth-tokens | sed -n 1p | awk 'NF>1{print $NF}'`
# Now configure App ID for Cloud Directory
FILENAME=".bluemix/appid-config.json"
curl -v -X PUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' \
           --header "Authorization: Bearer $IAM_OAUTH_TOKEN" \
           -d @$FILENAME  $APPID_MGMT_URL/config/idps/cloud_directory
```

I found the code above in this [deploy script](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/insurance-bot/blob/dev/.bluemix/pipeline-DEPLOY.sh) which is part of a [demo](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cloudco-insurance) with multiple services and microservice architecture.